# Suddenly includegraphics stopped working

Tags: floats, texmaker, includegraphics, compilation-error

I've been compiling for 1 week and everything was fine. Now it suddenly stopped working. I am a newbie using TexMaker.

I am doing the inclusions of figures like this:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Figures/phase_space_intr}
\decoRule
\caption[Example phase space]{bla bla bla [bla bla]}
\label{fig:depiction_phase_space}
\end{figure}
```

Every time i try to compile i get Latex error file not found. The files are there in the folder Figures where they ve been since the beginning.

Some ideas? I would try to restart Windows because all the source files are located in a GDrive folder and Gdrive is currently down (it has some sync problem) but I cannot turn the PC off because intensive computation is in progress and I can't waste other 2 days.

When it stopped compiling I had just recompiled adding a reference to a new equation. I tried to remove all the last added part but no way...

Comment: A wild guess, but did you add a `\graphicspath` somewhere in your file?

Comment: Did you cleared all output files before recompiling?

Comment: common error that causes that is to use latex instead of pdflatex (so then for example it stops looking for png files)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, it was not specified and it used to compile anyway.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle...I don't know what i was using before...it fixed the problem anyhow...thaks a lot

Answer (score 1):

A common error that causes that is to use latex instead of pdflatex (so then for example it stops looking for png files)